# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, gaussian-integral

Given that the derivative of $e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}$  is $e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}$ $ * \frac{-x}{a}$,
and that   $\int_{0}^{\infty}x*e^{\frac{-x^2}{2a}} = 1$

I need to calculate  $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}dx$.

I've been trying to do this using integration in parts, but I've failed in every attempt.

### $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{a}*e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}dx = \frac{x}{a}|_{0}^{\infty}*\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})} - \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})} $

### $1 = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}(\frac{x}{a}|_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{a})$

### $\frac{1}{\frac{x}{a}|_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{a}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}$

$0 = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(\frac{-x^2}{2a})}$

It can't be 0 since it's the gaussian integral.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The integral in the second line is $a$ and not $1$ (in general). I would substitute $x=\sqrt{2a} t$ and use the standard gaussian integral.

Comment: The integral is not solvable with conventional direct methods. [Take your pick of one of the eleven proofs given here.](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the property of normal distribution that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a}}dx =\sqrt{2\pi a}$. At the same time, since the integrand is an even function $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a}}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a}}dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi a}{2}}$$